# Write write module to a new file

Tags: node.js

I have the following logic that imports a typescript module and makes some changes to it. Below is the simplified version of code.

```
const fs = require('fs')

// No deep nestings, and no arrays (only simple key: `string-values`)
const POSTCSS_SELECTORS = {
  propA: `value`,
  probB: `value`
}

fs.write('fileName.js', POSTCSS_SELECTORS)
```

After obtaining `POSTCSS_SELECTORS` I would like to save the output as commonjs module as described below.

**Expected output:**
`fileName.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  propA: `value`,
  probB: `value`
}
```

I will appreciate a lot if you could suggest a valid workaround for this case :)

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output? i.e. what you would expect to see. Also, is it safe to presume `POSTCSS_SELECTORS` are one-level only?

Comment: I've just updated the question with the expected output, and yes the object is a simple key: stringValue storage :-)

Comment: seems like the context of the question has changed a lot, so you no longer need to write to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 95% there, you just need to write out the rest of the text that you  want in your file:

```
const fs = ...
const POSTCSS_SELECTORS = ...

// prepare that object for writing to file:
const json = JSON.stringify(POSTCSS_SELECTORS, false, 2);

// and then "template" it into the final text you want written.
fs.writeFile(`filename.js`, `module.exports = ${jsonForm}`);
```

***But***, if you have a file with a hardcoded variable called `POSTCSS_SELECTORS`, why not make a file called `postcss_selectors.js` instead, and put the hardcoded object *there*, instead? No need to "make a file based on this object" if what you want is that object, as a module.

Just make that module.

Comment: `fs.write` uses a file descriptor as first parameter. For a path, you need to use `fs.writeFile`

Comment: Also, depending on the node version, you might need a callback or you will get an error or a warning, but this is out of the question's scope.

Comment: I'll let @volna decide whether they want a callback or writeFileSync.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions guys, reading the suggestion that there is actually no need to write a file but just directly export indeed makes sense. So I went this way instead. Thank you once again to everybody :-)

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the missing 5% - it's not just as simple as `JSON.strjngify`. to generate a valid CSS file.

Comment: Except that the question wasn't about generating a valid CSS file, it was about generating a node module that exported an object with property:value pairs =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans d'oh, my mistake, led by the naming ‍♂️ I have the downvote on this, if you edit I will remove :)